# Can I shorten this? Created a process in vb.net - have to call it 4 times

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, unix

Also for some reason it was working yesterday but it isn't working today. I don't think its the code but some external matter.

Anyways

```
    Dim virtualFolder As String = "~/Scripts/"
    Dim physicalFolder As String = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder)
    Dim unixLogin As String = (USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & ":" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME)

    ' Send file to Unix server via pscp
    Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
    'MsgBox("/C C:\pscp.exe -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & physicalFolder & "\" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME & " " & unixLogin)
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\pscp.exe -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & physicalFolder & "\" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME & " " & USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & ":" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    'Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()
    ' Allows script to execute sequentially instead of simultaneously
    Proc.WaitForExit()

    ' Make file executable
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\plink.exe")
    'MsgBox("-ssh -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & " chmod u+x ./" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME)
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & " chmod u+x ./" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    ' Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()
    Proc.WaitForExit()

    ' Execute File
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\plink.exe")
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & " ./" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    'Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()
    Proc.WaitForExit()

    ' Remove File
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\plink.exe")
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & " rm ./" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    'Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()
    Proc.WaitForExit()
```

Can this be shortened?
I am...
1) Sending a file to a unix system
2) Making it executable
3) Running the file (its a script)
4) Deleting it after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to see if this will work for you. I do not have an Unix system to check it on, but it seems to populate the process correctly. I also dummied up default values for your variables for testing purposes. This takes away a lot of the redundancy and shortens the amount of code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim USERNAME As String = "USERNAME"
    Dim COMPUTERNAME As String = "COMPUTERNAME"
    Dim UNIXSCRIPTNAME As String = "UNIXSCRIPTNAME"
    Dim PASSWORD As String = "PASSWORD"
    Dim virtualFolder As String = "~/Scripts/"
    Dim physicalFolder As String = "physicalFolder"
    Dim unixLogin As String = (USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & ":" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME)
    Dim processCmdFileTransfer As String = "C:\pscp.exe -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & physicalFolder & "\" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME & " " & USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & ":" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME
    Dim processCmdFileActions As String = "-ssh -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & USERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & "XX" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        test()
    End Sub

    Public Sub test()

        RunProcess("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", processCmdFileTransfer)
        RunProcess("C:\plink.exe", processCmdFileActions, " chmod u+x ./")
        RunProcess("C:\plink.exe", processCmdFileActions, " ./")
        RunProcess("C:\plink.exe", processCmdFileActions, " rm ./")

    End Sub

    Private Sub RunProcess(processPath As String, startInfo As String, Optional command As String = "")


        Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(processPath)

        If (InStr(startInfo, "XX") > 0) And (command <> "") Then
            startInfo = startInfo.Replace("XX", command)
        End If


        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = startInfo
        Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
        Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Proc.Start()
        Proc.WaitForExit()

    End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Sorry I haven't commented back. I will check this out at work tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @envinyater no problem, let me know if there are any issues